# When a website says a font is "Free for personal use", am i allowed to use it in a name card?

Tags: fonts

I have an amateur question to ask. Following the title of the question, if the website says free for personal use, am i allowed to the font and print it on my name card (business card)? I dont own or work for any company. Im an independent artist who would like to hand out name cards when engaged in some events etc. Many thanks in advance to your answers.

Comment: If your intention is to gain financially, or marketing with the end goal of financial gain, don't use "Free for personal use" intellectual property. The right thing to do is either buy a license for the font if one is available for it, or find a suitable free for commercial use font. There are plenty of free for commercial use fonts out there. The bottom line is: If you make money from someone else's art, you should pay them.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, personal use means you can not use this image to make money. 
If you give your business cards just so that your friends would have your data - it's ok. 
If you're hoping to win new clients or business contacts through business cards then this is not personal use anymore.
This is how I see it.